# Regex to not match when not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to create a JS Regex that matches double spaces

```
([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\w\/]\s\s[^\s])
```

The RegEx should match double spaces (not including the start or end of a line, when wrapped within quotes).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

For example:

```
var x = 1,
    Y = 2;
```

Would be fine where as

```
var x =  1;
```

would not (more than one space after the `=` sign.

Also if it was

```
console.log("I am some console  output");
```

would be fine as it is within double quotes

Comment: There are a number of similar questions in the **Related** list. Did you try any of them before posting your question?

Comment: What do you want to do with the match? Remove or replace the double-whitespace? Find the position?

Comment: @try-catch-finally I hope this edit meets your need

Answer (score 4):

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

We can solve it with a beautifully-simple regex:

```
(["'])  \1|([ ]{2})
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `'  '` and `"  "`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures double spaces to Group 2, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex in JavaScript, where we will retrieve the Group 2 captures:

```
var the_captures = []; 
var string = 'your_test_string'
var myregex = /(["'])  \1|([ ]{2})/g;
var thematch = myregex.exec(string);
while (thematch != null) {
    // add it to array of captures
    the_captures.push(thematch[2]);
    document.write(thematch[2],"<br />");    
    // match the next one
    thematch = myregex.exec(string);
}
```

**A Neat Variation for Perl and PCRE**

In the original answer, I hadn't noticed that this was a JavaScript question (the tag was added later), so I had given this solution:

```
(["'])  \1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[ ]{2}
```

Here, thanks to `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` magic, we can directly match the spaces, without capture groups.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU4mT4/1).

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: If the "`requirements are not entirely clear to [you]`", you should consider first to ask for clarification in the comments section rather than shallow answering. (Edit: the downvote was mine ;)

Comment: this seems to still match
console.log('should allow multiple  Spaces 1!')

Comment: @NickWhite It's not about the match, but about the Group 2 capture. The code retrieves Group 2. This is a "SKIP" technique that matches what we don't want in order to capture what we do want. Will add explanation. Please see the sample code.

Comment: The code does not work yet: you're creating `regex` but using `myregex`. And it's still not clear (obviously not only to me) what Nick White excpects. Tip: you may use head-controlled `while` to spare one `exec()`: `do { ... } while (...);` :)

Comment: @try-catch-finally `regex` vs. `myregex` = good catch, thank you. :) Have a look at the answer... If you still think it should be downvoted, you have amazingly high standards, and I'll need to go learn from your answers. :)

Comment: I prefer to vote on the spirit of the answer, and not whether the answer fully compiles or is 100% optimized. If the regex or overall approach is correct, then downvoting is pedantically useless or uselessly pedantic (they are commutative properties in this case :D ). You can constructively comment without downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

```
/\s{2,}/
```

This matches all occurrences of one or more whitespace characters. If you need to match the entire line, but only if it contains two or more consecutive whitespace characters:

```
/^.*\s{2,}.*$/
```

If the whitespaces don't need to be consecutive:

```
/^(.*\s.*){2,}$/
```

Comment: Where does your regexp avoid matching spaces that are inside quotes?

Comment: The regex in the question ensures that it also doesn't match spaces at the start of the line

Comment: This ignores quotes. -1 for that reason.